# Alguém sabe explicar porque isso é possível? C++

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class S
{
public:
    S()
    {

    }

    S& operator=(S&)
    {
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    S s;

    s = S(); // passando um rvalue como argumento para uma função
             // (copy assignment) que só aceita lvalue


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Alguém saberia me explicar porque o copy assignment é chamado nesse caso? até onde sei, isso só deveria compilar se o parâmetro do copy assignment fosse const S& onde seria possível passar um rvalue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha cara, aqui tanto no GCC 7.3.0 quanto no Clang 5.0.1 isso nem compila pelo exato motivo que você disse, a assinatura do copy assignment está errada:

```
[phoemur@notebook_lenovo.darkstar ~/cpp/teste]$g++ -o teste teste.cpp -Wall
teste.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
teste.cpp:24:9: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘S&’ to an rvalue of type ‘S’
 s = S(); // passando um rvalue como argumento para uma função
     ^~~
teste.cpp:13:8: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘S& S::operator=(S&)’
 S& operator=(S&)
    ^~~~~~~~
[phoemur@notebook_lenovo.darkstar ~/cpp/teste]$clang++ -o teste teste.cpp -Wall
teste.cpp:24:7: error: no viable overloaded '='
s = S(); // passando um rvalue como argumento para uma função
~ ^ ~~~
teste.cpp:13:8: note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
S& operator=(S&)
```

As assinaturas dos construtores devem ser igual ao do padrão se não não compila:

> ```
> default constructor: X()
> copy constructor: X(const X&)
> copy assignment: X& operator=(const X&)
> move constructor: X(X&&)
> move assignment: X& operator=(X&&)
> destructor: ~X()
> ```

Comment: Valeu, essa não é a primeira 'anomalia' que eu presencio no visual c++.

Comment: @StrawberrySwing se essa resposta consegue satisfatoriamente resolver seu questionamento, pode marcar ela como aceita clicando no ✅. Esse é o maior agradecimento que pode fazer